# Connecting an .cshtml page after user has successfully log in using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I connect my cshtml page to the login page .I'm using MVC in c# .

Comment: i understand nothing ^^'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is not clear.Refer this and understand how to ask a question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can user this to redireact the .cshtml

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller");
```